# ITunesConnect - unable to select build

Tags: xcode, build, app-store-connect

I am using Xcode 8 and I am trying to submit a newer version of my app to iTunesConnect. However I could not select any build version even though I tried to change the build number. See screenshot

[image: Itunes build section image]

I also tried waiting for a couple of hours with no impact.

Comment: Goto activity tab, and see wether your build is `processing`

Comment: Click on Activity tab and check your builds status. If they're not verified you can't add them

Comment: No it wasn't showing it for me although I submitted multiple builds for the same version. I have posted my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

Surprisingly Apple started sending out emails which tells you why your build wasn't accepted. I didn't see this email until the next day.

> Dear developer,
>
> We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for . To process your delivery, the following issues must be corrected:
>
> This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an NSContactsUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.
>
> Once these issues have been corrected, you can then redeliver the corrected binary.
>
> Regards,
>
> The App Store team

Once I fixed the issues and re-submitted the binary, I didn't see my build instantly. However after 10min or so, I get an email from Apple

> iTunes Connect: Version 5.2  has completed processing.

Now when I look at iTunes .. the plus symbol next to the 'Build' section appears.

[image: Build with plus symbol]

Hope this post helps others who run into the same issue.